# Issue when Declaring a ComboBox Object using C# code

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox, windows-phone-8

I'm making a program for window phone using silverlight.

I have a small problem and it is about creating a combo box.

I can create it using xaml, but I am in a situation where I should declare it using c# code.

The problem is after creating a new instance of the combo box and adding the items to it, the combo box doesn't appear!!

The code:

```
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "Select your arrival status";

        tb.Margin = new Thickness(5.0);
        tb.FontSize = 20;
        tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        ObservableCollection<string> testList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        testList.Add("Hi");
        testList.Add("Hi1");
        testList.Add("Hi2");
        cb.DataContext = testList;
        cb.Height = 50;
        cb.Width = 200;
        cb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        panel.Children.Add(tb);
        panel.Children.Add(cb);
```

As you can see from the code, I have declared a TextBlock and a Combobox objects. The TextBox object appears whereas the the Combobox doesn't.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of element is panel? Panel is an abstract class, so it your panel a Canvas, Grid, StackPanel?  They all behave differently when adding children to them.

Comment: Have you given a Name to the ComboBox?  Not sure that it will do anything, but worth a shot.

Comment: I gave it a name, but that did't solve the problem.

Comment: Could it be because you're setting the Foreground (text) to white, so you just can't see your combobox?

Comment: I don't think so. I removed the TextBlock and I got the exact same problem

Comment: You could test cb.visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.visible. By default, it should be visible but who knows ? Also, how have you defined your stackpanel ? Maybe the combobox doesn't fit the stackpanel

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it a position.  Your combo box is most likely under your text box.  Either create the two of them using the designer and xaml, or be sure to assign x,y coordinates to them.  Use the Margin property as well as HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem. I removed the textblock completely, but the combobox still doesn't appear.

Comment: @user2073081 any reason you are attempting to lay this out on the fly instead of building an xaml in the designer?

Comment: I want to add the ComboBox and other UI elements in a PopUp instance.

Comment: Then put them in a `UserControl` and show that in the `Popup`. That would allow use to use XAML to design the `UserControl`.